# Bootstrap datetimepicker mindate

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker in my web app to show datetimepicker.

I have 2 controls - `startDate and endDate`
I want to set `minDate` for `'endDate'` as greater than `'startDate'`.

This plugin provides an option of `'minDate'`.
However, how do I set the value for it from another datetimepicker field?

I tried to do as follows.

```
$('#start-date-time-datepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment(),
    sideBySide: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});

$('#end-date-time-datepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: $('#start-date-time-datepicker').val(),
    sideBySide: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});
```

But it is not working.

Can someone please provide some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the date pickers

```
$(function () {
    $('#start_date').datetimepicker({
     // custom config
    });
    $('#end_date').datetimepicker({
        // custom config
    });
    $("#start_date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#end_date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#end_date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#start_date').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

ref: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `$("#start-date-time-datepicker").data("DateTimePicker").date()` or `$("#start-date-time-datepicker").find("input").val()` to get the value you want.

Here's a simple demo.

```js
var $start = $('#start-date-time-datepicker'),
    $end1 =  $('#end-date-time-datepicker1'),
    $end2 =  $('#end-date-time-datepicker2')

$start.datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment(),
    sideBySide: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});

$end1.datetimepicker({
    minDate: $start.data("DateTimePicker").date(),
    sideBySide: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});

$end2.datetimepicker({
    // note that this is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format
    // $("#start-date-time-datepicker").find("input").val()

    minDate: new Date($start.find("input").val()),
    sideBySide: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});

$start.on('dp.change', function(){
  // $start input change event
  var startDate = $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date();
  
  // set $end1 and $end2 to $start's date and set the minDate
  $end1.data("DateTimePicker").options({
    date: startDate,
    minDate: startDate
  })
  
  $end2.data("DateTimePicker").options({
    date: startDate,
    minDate: startDate
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class='input-group date' id='start-date-time-datepicker'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class='input-group date' id='end-date-time-datepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class='input-group date' id='end-date-time-datepicker2'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hikarunomemory, thanks for the reply. However, if I first select the start date, I want my end date to be automatically set to the start date. This is not happening. I want user to put restriction that end date should be greater than start date. Is it possible?

Comment: @VishalBhavsar I updated the snippet. Please take a look.